# Problems with scroll-bar on a widget from Nasa

Tags: css, iframe

I am trying to incorporate a widget from Nasa on my website, but I'm a total noob at coding, so if someone could help me I would appreciate it. Here is the code from the widget:

```
<div style='display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -o-border-radius: 6px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 310px; height: 450px;'><iframe src='https://spotthestation.nasa.gov/widget/widget2.cfm' width='310' height='450' frameborder='0' ></iframe></div>
```

When I copy the code (copy paste from nasa's code) in a css section, the widget displays with a scroll-bar but normally it shouldn't have the scroll bar to it and it should display entirely.

I have tried to change the "position:" and "overflow:" elements but to no avail. Can someone help me with this please? Thanks you

Comment: Here is the link from NASA where they give the code to the widget: https://spotthestation.nasa.gov/widget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't have a scrollbar here:

Maybe you have it in a wrapper that's smaller than your DIV?

```html
<div class= "wrap">
<div style='display:inline-block; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -o-border-radius: 6px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 310px; height: 450px;'><iframe src='https://spotthestation.nasa.gov/widget/widget2.cfm' width='310' height='450' frameborder='0' ></iframe></div>
</div>
```